# Is there any way in laravel to find those values that are not exist in pivot table in many to many relationships?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

For example i have two tables

1. Context
   a. id
   b. name
2. Course
   a. id
   b. name

Now I find out all the context that is not inside a course?

Comment: But better way to create a `raw` SQL query and transform it to your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `NOT IN` clouse in your query. That is how it looks on Yii2, it does looks similar in Laravel:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['not in', 
                'product.id',
                CompanyProductConfiguration::find()
                    ->select(['company_product_configuration.product_id'])
                    ->where(['company_id' => $this->company_id])
                    ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'company_product_configuration.product_status', self::STATUS_DISABLED])
            ]);
```